# Can't set TTS's paras via button

Tags: android, button, text-to-speech

I tried to set TTS's paras such as pitch and speech rate by pressing a button, but somehow nothing changes when I pressed it...

See the code following, what I planned is that once I press the button **SetPara**, the **_pitch** and **_rate** will be set to 0.5, and

```
tts.setPitch(_pitch);
tts.setSpeechRate(_rate);
```

will set TTS's pitch and speech rate to 0.5, but the problem now is that after I pressed the **SetPara** button the pitch and speech rate didn't change...

Please help me out :))))

```
package com.example.text2speechtrail;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;
private Button btnSetPara;

private EditText getPitch;
private EditText getRate;
public float _pitch;
public float _rate;
String _string_pitch = null;

String _string_rate =  null;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSetPara = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setPara);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    getPitch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getPitch);

    getRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getRate);

    btnSetPara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    SetPara();
    }

    });

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            speakOut();
        }

    });
}

public void SetPara(){

    _pitch = (float) 0.5;
    _rate = (float) 0.5;

  }  
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {


        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

        tts.setPitch(_pitch);
        tts.setSpeechRate(_rate);


        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}


private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set on click listener for your btnSetPara button

```
btnSetPara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        SetPara();
    }

});
```

You do not need the param View  in setPara

```
public void SetPara(){

_pitch = (float) 0.5;
_rate = (float) 0.5;
if (tts != null) {
    tts.setPitch(_pitch);
    tts.setSpeechRate(_rate);
    }
}  


private void speakOut() {

String text = txtText.getText().toString();

tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Comment: You need to setSpeech and setRate in your speak method. Actually it is better to set it in SetPara

Comment: What kind of error? probably tts is not initialize yet, should set btnSetPara disable in your xml file and enable in onInit

Comment: I am pretty sure because onInit has not been called when you pressed so disable the button as I suggested because the same thing would happen if you put the setSpeech and setRate in speak

Comment: Doing as you suggested now :) It make sense!